# getting error of undefine column its confusing me why this happen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i had created a coulmn name Active in pqsql
when i m update value from laravel
here is my controller

```
    public function updatenotification($id)
  {
    $affected = DB::update('update users set Active = 1 where id = ?',     
   [$id]);
    return view('admin.dashboard.index');
  }
```

here is my view

```
     @foreach($users1 as $task)
                       <tr>
                       <td><span>{{ $task->name }}</span></td>
                       <td><span>Waiting for Approval</span></td>
                       <td>

                       <span><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{ 
                       url('admin/notificationshow',array($task->id)) 
                      }}">Approve</a></span>

                       </td>


                       </tr>
                       @endforeach
```

i m getting error this below, i also checked in database coulmn exits but still getting error
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "active" of relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: update users set Active = 1 where id = $1
^ (SQL: update users set Active = 1 where id = 1)

what i m doing wrong... i had create this Active column directing into pgsql 
also i had check weather its spell mistake but its not

Comment: Your column is "Active" or "active" ? I guess pgsql is also case sensitive.

Comment: its " Active" in both places in my controller and pgsql

Comment: Did you try to manually execute your query to your pgsql server ?

Comment: no just manually added a "Active" coulmn and set it default

Answer (score 2):

Why not using eloquent? Probably `DB::update` method is lowercasing your query that being the reason for the error thrown.

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->Active = 1;
$user->save();

return view('admin.dashboard.index');
```

To avoid this kind of issues simply use lowercase strings for db columns.

Comment: It's what I thought about lowercasing but judging by the returned error, it seems to not being altered. Btw, your solution is cleaner.

Comment: It is altered: `7 ERROR: column "active"`. The column written in the error is lowercased instead of `Active`

Comment: Yes, but just after I'm guessing it's the executed request : "SQL: update users set Active = 1 where id = 1". But you may be right.

@Bipin Just try to lowercase your column in database without changing your request. You'll also know if Laravel's query builder is lowercasing before executing.

Comment: thanks that solve my issue big thank you guys for help